# What should I name my install instructions for ubuntu centric applications?

Tags: packaging, development, debian

Just wondering if there was a standard for this sort of thing, particularly for debian packages.

I see in here for the license, `LICENSE.LGPL`

I'd like to add some install instructions to my own, but am not sure if I should name it

- `INSTALL.txt`
- `INSTALL.TXT`
- `INSTALL`
- `install.txt`
- `install`
- `README`
- `readme.txt`

... you get the idea. Debian or Ubuntu must have a template or standard for this sort of thing, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no particular standard you must follow with it.

*README* and *INSTALL* are intended to be separate things, though. Generally, *README* is content describing what the package is, and *INSTALL* is describing how to install it. If you use GNU autotools, it follows the scheme of having a *README* and *INSTALL* file. If you have source on *GitHub*, it expects a *README.md* in markdown format, which it uses to generate some HTML at the project tree root. You can name the file however you want.

If you are using a standard build system in your project, then it is generally obvious how one should build and install the package (assuming the source code isn't broken with hard-coded values that contradict with the build system). In some cases it may be necessary to explain what additional flags one may provide to *cmake* for example, to configure parts of your package in a different way from the defaults.